# Cleveref and nameinlink – problem with some environments/names

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, hyperlink

I have a problem with the `cleveref` that is exemplified in the following piece of code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%

\theoremstyle{plain}
%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}


\theoremstyle{definition}
%
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
%
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
%
\newcommand{\MathRef}[2][blue]{%
\hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}%
\Cref{#2}%
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Bla]
\label{bla}
Bla
\end{definition}

\MathRef{bla}

\begin{problem}[Blabla]
\label{blabla}
Blabla
\end{problem}

\MathRef{blabla}

\begin{condition}[Blabla]
\label{blablabla}
Blabla
\end{condition}

\MathRef{blablabla}

\begin{conjecture}[Bla]
\label{bla1}
Bla
\end{conjecture}

\MathRef{bla1}

\end{document}
```

As it can be noticed, the command `MathRef` works well only in the first case, while in the others for – I guess – different reasons, it does not. It looks like `cleveref` misses the name of some of these environements.

What is the issue?
How can it be solved?

Any feedback will be mostly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `theorem` definitions are occuring too early, i.e. before `cleveref` is loaded, as such, `cleveref` has no 'grip' to provide a correct `\crefname` etc.

Push the definitions **after** loading `cleveref`.

The reason, why `theorem` and `definition` work out of the box is that `cleveref` has a built-in support for those theorem names (better counters) already.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}


\theoremstyle{plain}
%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}


\theoremstyle{definition}
%
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}


%
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
%
\newcommand{\MathRef}[2][blue]{%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}%
  \Cref{#2}%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Bla]
\label{bla}
Bla
\end{definition}

\MathRef{bla}

\begin{problem}[Blabla]
\label{blabla}
Blabla
\end{problem}

\MathRef{blabla}

\begin{condition}[Blabla]
\label{blablabla}
Blabla
\end{condition}

\MathRef{blablabla}

\begin{conjecture}[Bla]
\label{bla1}
Bla
\end{conjecture}

\MathRef{bla1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed it works fine. But – just out of curiosity – why did it work before but only for definition and not for the others?

Comment: @Kolmin: `definition` is already provided by `cleveref` since that environment name occurs quite often.